# If event A is independent with event B, then is the subset of A is independent with B?

Tags: probability

Condition: A and B is independent

Question: Is the subset of A is independent with B?

Comment: Pick a card from a standard deck. Let $A$ be the event it is an ace and $B$ be the event it is red. Let $C\subset A$ be the event it is a black ace.

Comment: Is your question "Does there exist a subset of $A$ that is also independent of $B$?" or "Is it the case that _all_ subsets of $A$ are also independent of $B$ (just as $A$ is independent of $B$)?" The answer to the first question is Yes, $\emptysubset$ is a subset of $A$ and is independent of $B$, while the answer to the second question is No as various answers already posted show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[assuming I correctly understood your question] Not necessarily: look at Venn's diagram. You can find $A' \subset A$ and $B' \subset B$ such that $A' \cap B' = \emptyset$. Clearly $P(\emptyset) = P(A')P(B')$ is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B$ and $C$ are dependent events. There is an event $A$ such that $C\subset A$ and $P(A)=1$. If $P(A)=1$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent.